# Find the limit of the following sequence?

Tags: limits

The n-th term of the sequence is given as $a_{n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-2}}+...+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}$

Fidning that $$b_{n}=\frac{n+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}<a_{n}<\frac{n+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}=c_{n}$$
Where $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ are equiconvergent sequnces, i.e. have the same limit, we conclude that the limit of the sequence $c_{n}$ must be the same also.
So coming back to my original question, I have trouble fining this limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}$$
By dividing both the denomerator and numerator with $n^{2}$
I get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{0}{\sqrt[3]{n^{2}-0}}=0$$
But zero is not given as the possible solution.

Comment: What is the set of answers offered to you?

Comment: It states that the limit is either 1, or 2. Maybe I should edit this question, to include the sequence upon which I used the sandwich theorem.

Comment: Your last expression's left side is wrong. There's no way you can get zero inside that square root. Nevertheless, the limit indeed is zero.

Comment: the limit shown is indeed 0. You say this is just a step to the original problem, and you came up with this step, but perhaps you should show up the original problem, perhaps your simplifying step was not right?

Comment: There, I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{n+2}{\sqrt[3]{n^6-1}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n} + \dfrac{2}{n^2}}{\sqrt[3]{1-\dfrac{1}{n^6}}} \rightarrow \dfrac{0+0}{1} = 0$.

Comment: Feel free to add math formalism in your answer. The arrow means nothing when nothing is embedded to it.